# Nginx docker compose - volume add nginx.conf (reverse proxy)

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I want to containerize my web applications. Currently, I am using **Apache** to provide a couple of **PHP** apps.

Every app should be provided by their own container.
Nginx should be reachable by **port 80/443**. Depending on the sub route it should proxying to one of the containers.

**For example:**

```
www.url.de/hello1 --> hello1:80
www.url.de/hello2 --> hello2:80
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
            image: nginx:latest
            container_name: reverse_proxy
            volumes:
                    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            ports:
                    - "80:80"
                    - "443:443"
            networks:
                    - app-network
            depends_on:
                    - hello1
                    - hello2

    hello1:
            build: ./test1
            image: hello1
            container_name: hello1
            expose:
                    - "80"
            networks:
                    - app-network
    hello2:
            build: ./test2
            image: hello2
            container_name: hello2
            expose:
                    - "80"
            networks:
                    - app-network

networks:
    app-network:
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
events {

}

http {
    error_log /etc/nginx/error_log.log warn;
    client_max_body_size 20m;

    proxy_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:500m max_size=1000m;


    server {
            server_name wudio.de;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://hello1:80;
            }

            location /hello1/ {
                    proxy_pass http://hello1:80;
                    rewrite ^/hello1(.*)$ $1 break;
            }

            location /hello2/ {
                    proxy_pass http://hello2:80;
                    rewrite ^/hello2(.*)$ $1 break;
            }

    }
}
```

If I run **docker-compose up -d**, only the container with image **webapp-test1** is online. And I also can reach it by `curl localhost:8081`.
Nginx is not running. If I remove the line in which I add **nginx.conf** to the volume of Nginx, it´s working.
What I´m doing wrong?

**Edit1:**

```
http:// was missing. But proxying still not working on subroutes. Only location / is working. How I get /hell1 running?
```

Comment: Do you have an error message, stacktrace or something similar?

Comment: unfortunately not. the process is running without any errors/stack trace. It looks like everything worked. But Nginx is not online. If I remove the volume, it works and Nginx is reachable at least by port 80

Comment: Run `docker logs nginx_container_id` to show error log of die nginx container

Comment: @RajeshGupta not me,

Comment: Try giving the full path of the nginx.conf file you are trying to map rather than relative path. I have an nginx container running similar to your requirement

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan nginx: [emerg] invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:11

Comment: which line is `11` in nginx ?

Comment: proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8081;

Comment: change to : `proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:8081` and build `nginx` container again

Comment: I did. It worked. But I get Error 502 Bad Gateway if I try to curl 127.0.0.1/test1
BUT the error message is from Nginx :)

Comment: instead of 127.0.0.1 you should use the container name. try http://hello1:8081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the proxy_pass statement. You have to mention the protocol in that statement. Also note how you can refer to the name of the service in your docker-compose.yml file (in this case hello1).

```
events {

}

http {
    error_log /etc/nginx/error_log.log warn;
    client_max_body_size 20m;

    proxy_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:500m max_size=1000m;

    server {
       listen 80;
       location / {
          try_files $uri @proxy ;
       }

       location @proxy {
          proxy_pass http://hello1:80/;
       }
    }
}
```

Edit: Try this instead

```
events {

}

http {
    error_log /etc/nginx/error_log.log warn;
    client_max_body_size 20m;

    proxy_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:500m max_size=1000m;

    server {
      listen 80;
      location / {
          try_files $uri @proxy ;
      }

      location @proxy {
          if ($request_uri ~* "^\/hello1(\/.*)$") {
            set $url "http://hello1:80$1";
          }

          if ($request_uri ~* "^\/hello2(\/.*)$") {
            set $url "http://hello2:80$1";
          }

          proxy_pass "$url"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok. definitely progress :). Nginx is running now. But it looks like that proxying doesn't work. I used proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081. But on curl localhost/test1 I get error 502 Bad Gateway.

Comment: Inside the nginx container, the loopback address will refer to the container not the host. You need to proxy it to the service which runs your other container (hello1 from your docker-compose file)

Comment: I edit my Question. Do you have an idea what´s wrong?

Comment: I modified the example in my answer. See if that helps.

Comment: thank you. but it is not working with multiple apps, right? or how I can map routes to the services?

Comment: Your docker-file shows only one app-container (hello1). Are there more than 1? If yes, can you provide some sample incoming URIs and tell how you would want them directed? I can help you create the write nginx configuration.

Comment: yes, you are right. I tried to break down my code as much as possible. I edit the change.  On this way only / is working. On /hell1 I get Error 404 not found by Nginx. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: When you give /hello1 nginx is passing everything including /hello1 to your hello1 container which does not know what to do with that URI. hence the 404 error. You can try modifying the location block for the proxy as shown in my example. Some changes may be required since I could not try this out in my environment.

Comment: sorry for late response. sometimes it works sometimes not :/. Current error is "/usr/share/nginx/html/hello1/index.html" is not found

Comment: Please share what your nginx.conf file looks like now.

Comment: I edit my config. now its working. I have no idea why but it´s working now :). Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: Would still be good to have the final working config file in the post to help future users of SO.

Comment: final working version is now in my post. Nginx is on build process depending on hello1,hello2 now. Maybe you edit your answer to that for futur users?

Comment: BTW. Do you know if it´s possible to deploy this on kubernetes?